# uv subdivision between blender and maya

Tags: texturing, uv

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I textured the model in maya and it looks good but when i imported the same  model into blender and add subsurf modifier level 2 then the texture looks distorted. Turning on the simple subdivision algorithm  instead of catmull-clark algorithm seems to fix the distortion but the mesh look very bad. Is there any solution for it[![enter image description here][2]][2]
Changing the uv boundary smoothing option from maya catmull-clark to preserve edges and corners  creates the same problem in Maya as in blender. Is there any similar option in blender to change the uv subdivision algorithm

Comment: i don't want to change the topology

Comment: Then there should be a way to convert smooth into actual geometry in Maya. It could be there aren't the same subdivision methods in Blender. Subsurf modifier provides only 2 methods you already tried. You can go with Subsurf at Simple method and either Smooth or Laplacian Smooth modifiers but again they might use another method.

Comment: Maybe unchecking subdivide UVs in subdivision modifier would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the Subdivide UVs setting on the subdivision modifier in blender.

This setting effectively determines whether vertexes are shifted when applying the subdivision to the Uvs or not. In particular, if simple is getting the projection you want, changing this setting will probably help

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a little bit more subdivisions on your model- preferably adding a bit more loopcuts, before adding a Subsurface Modifier.

Comment: ya changing the topology will work i tried that but i wanted to make it work  without making any changes to the topology. i guess there are no option to change the uv subdivision to hold the borders tight like maya. This makes harder to  move the 3d assert between one 3d program to another program.

Comment: Maybe you have already tried this but... since its a bit unfair for you not to get the same result as Maya wanna try changing the texture a bit? With blender texture painter. Only option that would actually work.

Comment: ya but changing the texture in blender makes it look different in maya. I guess there is no easy way to fix this.

Comment: Why do you want the model to use back in Maya again? What are you really going to do?

Comment: because i use blender for work but the client uses maya for their work